# How can I save data of EditText of a Fragment?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

I am developing an Android app that consists of fragments. I refer `developer.android.com` for this. For small devices, my `fragment_container.xml` file is replaced by the corresponding `fragment.xml` file.

The new fragment created consists of several edittext boxes and datepickers or so. I can save the data entered into the edittext boxes during screen orientation change somehow. But the text in the datepicker and lists get reset automatically.

And also, I want to save the content of the fragments so that if a user returns to the same fragment again, all the data he entered must be preserved.

I am new to Android.

This is my **MainActivity.java** class file:

```
        ContentFragment newFragment = new ContentFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        // Log.d("Inside OnCOntentSelected", String.valueOf(position));
        args.putInt(ContentFragment.ARG_POSITION, position);
        newFragment.setArguments(args);
        FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager()
                .beginTransaction();

        // Replace whatever is in the fragment_container view with this
        // fragment,
        // and add the transaction to the back stack so the user can
        // navigate back
        transaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, newFragment);
        transaction.addToBackStack(null);

        // Commit the transaction
        transaction.commit();
```

This is my **ContentFragment.java** code:

```
       import android.os.Bundle;
       import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
       import android.view.LayoutInflater;
       import android.view.View;
       import android.view.ViewGroup;
       import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
       import android.widget.Spinner;

public class ContentFragment extends Fragment {

public static final String ARG_POSITION = "position";
int mCurrentPosition = -1;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    // If activity recreated (such as from screen rotate), restore
    // the previous article selection set by onSaveInstanceState().
    // This is primarily necessary when in the two-pane layout.
    if (savedInstanceState != null) {
        mCurrentPosition = savedInstanceState.getInt(ARG_POSITION);

    }

    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    return inflater
            .inflate(R.layout.personal_information, container, false);
}

@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();

    // During startup, check if there are arguments passed to the fragment.
    // onStart is a good place to do this because the layout has already
    // been
    // applied to the fragment at this point so we can safely call the
    // method
    // below that sets the article text.
    // Log.d("Inside OnStart", "Inside OnStart");
    // Log.d("mCurrentPosition OnStart", String.valueOf(mCurrentPosition));
    Bundle args = getArguments();
    if (args != null) {
        // Set article based on argument passed in
        updateContentView(args.getInt(ARG_POSITION));
    } else if (mCurrentPosition != -1) {
        // Set article based on saved instance state defined during
        // onCreateView
        updateContentView(mCurrentPosition);
    }
    
    

}

public void updateContentView(int position) {
    

    mCurrentPosition = position;
    // if (mCurrentPosition == 0) {
    Spinner spinner = (Spinner) getActivity().findViewById(
            R.id.spinnerZodiac);
    // Create an ArrayAdapter using the string array and a default
    // spinner layout
    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(
            this.getActivity(), R.array.zodiac_signs,
            android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
    // Specify the layout to use when the list of choices appears
    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    // Apply the adapter to the spinner
    spinner.setAdapter(adapter);

    Spinner spinner1 = (Spinner) getActivity().findViewById(
            R.id.spinnerGender);
    // Create an ArrayAdapter using the string array and a default
    // spinner layout
    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter1 = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(
            this.getActivity(), R.array.gender,
            android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
    // Specify the layout to use when the list of choices appears
    adapter1.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    // Apply the adapter to the spinner
    spinner1.setAdapter(adapter1);
    // }

}

@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    
    outState.putInt(ARG_POSITION, mCurrentPosition);

    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

**TL;DR Use a ViewModel**

For this, you need to make a ViewModel. When you rotate the screen, lifecycle are triggered, and the whole fragment is destroyed and remade again for the new layout. But a ViewModel will not. From the documentation:

> The ViewModel class is designed to store and manage UI-related data in a lifecycle conscious way. The ViewModel class allows data to survive configuration changes such as screen rotations.
> [Source](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel)

So, how do you make one?

```java
public class ContentViewModel extends ViewModel {
   // text inputfield
   public String inputUser = "";
}
```

Then in your `ContentFragment`:

```java
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
   setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
   // Make the viewmodel
   myViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(ContentViewModel.class);
}
```

Next you need to add a `addTextChangedListener`

```java
myTextBox.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
 
   public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
   }
 
   public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, 
     int count, int after) {
   }
 
   public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, 
     int before, int count) {
   // Here save the result to the ViewModel
   myViewModel.inputUser = s; // This should be the new input
   }
  });
```

And then when you rotate your screen you only need to make a function that updates the field in the UI according to the data in the viewmodel.

```java
// Call this in the onCreate
public void updateUI() {
   myTextBox.text = myViewModel.inputUser;
}
```

You can read more [here](https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/viewmodels-a-simple-example-ed5ac416317e).
I'm, not a java programmer, so I hope that I got it right here, normally I make this in Kotlin, so keep that in mind if I made a mistake somewhere.